# How do I substitute bytes in a stream using Go standard library?

Tags: json, go

I have a `io.Reader` which I get from `http.Request.Body` that reads a JSON byte slice from a server.

I would like to stream this to `json.NewDecoder`. However I would also like to intercept the JSON before it hits `json.NewDecoder` and substitute certain parts of it. For example, the JSON string contains empty hashes "{}" which I would like to remove due to a bug in the server's JSON output.

I am currently achieving my goal using `json.Unmarshal` but not using the JSON streaming parser:

```
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
data = bytes.Replace(data, []byte("{}"), "", -1)
json.Unmarshal(data, [my struct])
```

How can I achieve the same thing as above but using `json.NewDecoder` so I can save the many times the above code has to parse through `r.Body`'s data? Here's some code using a pseudo function `ReplaceStream(r io.Reader, old, new []byte)`:

```
reader := ReplaceStream(r.Body, []byte("{}"), "")
dec := json.NewDecoder(reader)
dec.Decode([my struct])
```

I know `ReplaceStream` might be fairly trivial to make, but is there anything in the standard library to do this that I am unaware of?

Comment: is the json actually invalid? If not, I'm wondering if you can just use omitempty tags for the struct and let it deal with empty struct tags.  An example of the json and struct would be helpful here if you want more help as well.

Comment: The JSON is valid and my first thought was to use `omitempty`. 'Unfortunately' the Go `encoding/json` package treats the JSON correctly. The JSON is essentially `{"list": [{"object": 1}, {"object": 2}, ...]}`. However when there are no objects in the "list" instead of the server outputting `{"list": []}` it outputs `{"list": [{}]}` which is interpreted as an empty object in the "list" instead of no objects in the "list".

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to just treat that kind of message as a special case and avoid the extra parsing / substituting for all the other requests

```
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
// FIXME: overcome bug #12312 of json server 
if data == `{"list": [{}]}` {
  return []
} 
// Normal datastruct ..
```

Comment: I thought about this but did not deem it a maintainable option because unfortunately the `{"list": [...]}` object can be embedded in other JSON structures making your `if data == ...` suggestion need to cater for a whole variety of potentially unknown scenarios. There is the possibility to use reflection and check the entire `[my struct]` generated from `json.Decode([my struct])` to remove any empty struct objects.

Comment: then you could implement http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler in your structure and handle that case there

Comment: This suggestion looks promising. I'll investigate.

Comment: The problem I find with [golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) is that I must now manually unmarshal all child objects within `"list"`, which can be complex in my case. If I use the standard `json.Unmarshal` function within the `UnmarshalJSON` method of `json.Unmarshaler` interface I get an infinite recursion as would be expected. I am going to play around with it some more as I think it could work though.